# Unable to exposing data to the remote API in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, xml-parsing

My class which i have annotated with @ExporteBean, , i have the getApi method, and also annotated with @Exported to my methods.

```
@Extension
@ExportedBean
public class Environments  {

  public Api getApi() {
      return new Api(this);
  }


 @Exported(name="lable")
  public Set<LabelAtom> getLabels(){
return Jenkins.getInstance().getLabelAtoms();
 }

@Exported
public List<ToolDescriptor<?>> getToolDescriptors(){
  List<ToolDescriptor<?>> descriptors = new ArrayList<ToolDescriptor<?>>();
  for (ToolDescriptor<?> descriptor : ToolInstallation.all()) {
    if (descriptor.getInstallations().length>0){
      descriptors.add(descriptor);
    }
  }
  return descriptors;
}
```

but the Output what i am getting is blank xml when moving to

```
<myURL...>/api/xml
```

but i want the value of the xml to be shown on the same URL.

as below.

```
 <supportedEnvironments>
<lable/>
<lable/>
<lable/>
<lable/>
<lable/>
<lable/>
<lable/>
<toolDescriptor/>
<toolDescriptor/>
<toolDescriptor/>
<toolDescriptor/>
<toolDescriptor/>
</supportedEnvironments>
```

what can i do that a get the values of the xml

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Please make Class Environment to extend from Plugin. Also, in your pom file, the name for your Artifact Id is your plugin name. You could have **only one** class in your Jenkins Plugin that extends from Plugin.

The code is modified as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

import org.kohsuke.stapler.export.Exported;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.export.ExportedBean;

import hudson.Extension;
import hudson.Plugin;
import hudson.model.Api;
import hudson.model.labels.LabelAtom;
import hudson.tools.ToolDescriptor;
import hudson.tools.ToolInstallation;


@Extension
@ExportedBean
public class Environments **extends Plugin** {

  public Api getApi() {
      return new Api(this);
  }


 @Exported(name="lable")
  public Set<LabelAtom> getLabels(){
return Jenkins.getInstance().getLabelAtoms();
 }

@Exported
public List<ToolDescriptor<?>> getToolDescriptors(){
  List<ToolDescriptor<?>> descriptors = new ArrayList<ToolDescriptor<?>>();
  for (ToolDescriptor<?> descriptor : ToolInstallation.all()) {
    if (descriptor.getInstallations().length>0){
      descriptors.add(descriptor);
    }
  }
  return descriptors;
}

}
```

And the below URL is called via browser:
http://myjenkins:8080/jenkins/plugin/myArtifactId/api/xml

And I got the below output in my Firefox browser:

```
<environments><lable/></environments>
```

More detailed analysis at :http://tons-of-technical.blogspot.in/2015/02/play-with-jenkins-remote-api.html

Thanks!

Comment: Link only answers tend to be discouraged, please extract the relevant information from the linked article and post it.